# what is api cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

From the [docs online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#ctp23):

> SQL Server 2019 CTP 2.3 Query Store supports the ability to force query execution plans for fast forward and static T-SQL and **API cursors**.

My question is: What is an API cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically with a static cursor in T-SQL, SQL Server queries all the data and throws it into tempdb and passes back a pointer that the client can use to navigate around the data.

They are hugely inefficient and scale very badly.

API cursors are very similar at the back end, and perform and scale just as badly. The only difference is that the client library (OLE-DB or ODBC) does the navigation at the back end for you, instead of you issuing T-SQL commands.

The lightest for the server is a client-side cursor. For those, SQL Server sends all the data to the client and lets it worry about navigating around within it.

Answer (score 0):

[Cursors - Cursor Implementations: Application programming interface (API) server cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/cursors?view=sql-server-2017)

> Application programming interface (API) server cursors API cursors
>   support the API cursor functions in OLE DB and ODBC. API server
>   cursors are implemented on the server. Each time a client application
>   calls an API cursor function, the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB
>   provider or ODBC driver transmits the request to the server for action
>   against the API server cursor.

Comment: i have read that stmt in msdn, can u please give some example.